# Sort list in Propertygrid in XAML

Tags: c#, sorting, xceed

Following this Topics [Xceed WPF propertyGrid show item for expanded collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36286530/xceed-wpf-propertygrid-show-item-for-expanded-collection), how is it possible with XAML to sort the list by Name when Binding to Classes ?
Everytime I would like to add a new Item it should be immediately sorted. It doesn't work because if I use Classes.orderby(x=>x.name) it breaks all the bindings?

Answer (score 0):

Hello After lot's of time the solution is at the same time and not, but here I gave you all the solution:
1) the getters and setter for your Observablecollection

```
   private TheCollection yourcollection;
  public TheCollection Yourcollection{
        get{
            yourcollection.CollectionChanged -= Your_CollectionChanged;

            // use sort-Extension to sort pointprofil
            yourcollection.Sort();
            // read CollectionChange-Event
            yourcollection.CollectionChanged += Your_CollectionChanged;
            return yourCollection;
        }
}
```

And your Collection have to inherit from ObservableCollection but at the Same time to get an Extension to sort()

here we go:

```
static class Extensions

    public static void Sort<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection) where T : IComparable
    {
        List<T> sorted = collection.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < sorted.Count(); i++)
            collection.Move(collection.IndexOf(sorted[i]), i);
    }
}

public class YourCollections : ObservableCollection<YourPoints>, ICustomTypeDescriptor, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

}
```

and YourPoints have to inherit from IComparable